# two problems with the (log) likelihood measure of evidentiary support

Tags: probability, evidence

This is basically a reference request.  I'm looking for literature on the two types of counter-example to the log likelihood measure of support for hypotheses which I discuss below.

First some background.  The fine-tuning argument for God is fascinating to me, because it seems to expose some very strange things about how we use probability to analyze the extent to which evidence supports a hypothesis.

I was reading Robin Collins on this, and he makes much of the likelihood measurement of confirmation:  Some observed evidence E is said to support a hypothesis H over some competing hypothesis G whenever P(E|H)>P(E|G).  This seems backwards to me.  Intuitively, it seems what we should really demand is for P(H|E)>P(G|E).  And you can't get that from P(E|H)>P(E|G) alone.

I have a low view of Christian apologetics, so at first I thought Collins was just full of it.  But then I read some of A.W.F. Edwards' book *Likelihood* (1992), where he argues for the log-likelihood function as a measure of evidentiary support.  We can use his definitions.

Fix an arbitrary nonzero constant c, and let L(H|E) be defined as c*P(E|H), called the **likelihood** of H, given E.  The presence of c is meant, I suppose, to prevent ourselves from thinking too much about L(H|E) as a probability measurement.  It disappears whenever we consider the **log-likelihood ratio** of two hypotheses H and G given evidence E, defined as

ℓ(H,G|E):=log[L(H|E)/L(G|E)].

Note that ℓ(H,G|E)>0 if and only if P(E|H)>P(E|G), matching Collins' confirmation principle.

Edwards spends some significant time arguing for ℓ as the preferred measurement of evidentiary support, and he's not the only one.  José Zalabardo, David Glass, and Mark McCartney, just to name a few, all give similar arguments for ℓ.  And moreover, they give some pretty compelling arguments *against* the probabilistic counterpart P(H|E)/P(G|E).

What I don't understand, though, is that there seem to be some pretty obvious counter-examples to ℓ, in the form of ad-hoc hypotheses.  This is acknowledged by Collins and other authors.  For instance, if you're dealt a random poker hand, you could formulate the hypothesis that a demon intervened supernaturally to make that hand appear.  According to ℓ, the demon hypothesis enjoys an enormous amount of support over the chance hypothesis; and yet clearly that can't be right.

Collins' solution is to simply restrict ℓ to non-ad-hoc hypotheses.  But something seems deeply suspicious about that move (almost, ironically, ad hoc!).  The idea, I thought, is to find a mathematical model of evidentiary support.  But the ad hoc counter-examples seem to show that this model is at best limited.  And if it's limited in some ways, it could easily be limited in other ways too.  How, then, can we hope to determine where it's appropriate and where it's not?

Here is another kind of counter-example:  Let's say that the demon hypothesis above is proposed *before* dealing the cards.  Now it's no longer ad hoc, and yet we still wouldn't want to say that it's significantly supported by the evidence.  Instead, we would say that the chance hypothesis is *dis*confirmed---to make way for a trickster or cheater hypothesis, presumably.  The upshot, then, is that having ℓ(H,G|E)>0 doesn't seem to be helpful in distinguishing between evidence *for* H on one hand, and evidence *against* G on the other.

So those are the two types of counter-examples I'm most interested in---although I'm also certainly interested to hear of any other problems with ℓ.  Can anyone recommend some reading material for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using log( P(E|H) / P(E|¬H) ) as a criterion of weight of evidence was developed by Alan Turing and I J Good when they were doing cryptanalysis at Bletchley Park during WW2. Good, in particular, was a consistent advocate of it and wrote many papers about it. These days, the branch of study that is concerned with non-deductive reasoning is called confirmation theory, and much of the work in this space continues to be concerned with probabilistic approaches to testing conjectures.

The literature is pretty enormous. You might start by going to the philpapers.org website and searching for papers by the following: I J Good, Ian Hacking, Richard Jeffrey, Branden Fitelson, Elliott Sober, Alan Hájek, Patrick Maher, Malcolm Forster, Kenny Easwaran. Many of the papers listed there are behind paywalls, but some are available free.

As to some of the issues you specifically mention, a demon hypothesis might be said by Bayesians to have a very low prior. The likelihood ratio bumps up its probability relative to the hypothesis of a random deal of the cards, but the posterior might still be very low, especially compared with a cheating hypothesis. Also, you must take into account the base rate: so many hands are dealt at the World Series of Poker that the probability of someone getting a straight flush is fairly high.

That said, Bayesian accounts work well in simple situations, but do not deliver a full formal epistemology. What we require of a good theory is that it has explanatory value as well as predictive power, and probability theory is good at measuring the latter but not the former.

As a PS, here is another issue with using likelihood ratios. Suppose I have an urn with 1000 marbles in it and I have two competing hypotheses about their colours. H1 is that one marble is red and the other 999 are black. H2 is that all the marbles are different colours, with one of them being red. I draw a marble at random and observe E - that the marble is red. Now it seems clear that this ought to count in favour of H2 against H1. On the supposition of H2 there is nothing surprising about drawing a red marble: I had to get some colour and it might as well be red as anything else. On the supposition of H1 it is surprising to get a red marble: I expected to get a black one. Now if you plug the numbers into Bayes in its comparative form, the ratio of the posteriors is equal to the ratio of the priors times the likelihood ratio.

P(H1|E) / P(H2|E) = ( P(H1) / P(H2) ) . ( P(E|H1) / P(E|H2) )

But P(E|H1) = P(E|H2) = 1/1000. Both hypotheses predict a red marble with the same probability, so the posteriors are unchanged. It seems we need to take into account not only what we actually observed, but what we might have observed but didn't. This however does not sit well with the [likelihood principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_principle).